# Can annotations be attached to methods

Tags: java, annotations

Must annotations, such as  `@SampleAnnotation`, be attached only to (placed before) a class declaration? Can we use the `@SampleAnnotation` tag just before a method we want to apply it to?

Comment: Consider the standard [`@Override`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) annotation, for an example that *only* makes sense when applied to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the annotation. Theses are the possible locations for an annotiation (from [javadoc `@Target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html):

```
> ANNOTATION_TYPE Annotation type declaration 
> CONSTRUCTOR Constructor declaration 
> FIELD Field declaration (includes enum constants)
> LOCAL_VARIABLE Local variable declaration METHOD Method declaration
> PACKAGE Package declaration 
> PARAMETER Parameter declaration 
> TYPE Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration
```

Comment: Thhanks for your quick response..... The actual problem is that I want to add an annotation(having 3 fields) to a method and then, get some value, say 'a', from a private variable and then assign the value of that variable 'a' to an element of an annotation.... but I am unable to do it unless i add an annotation to the class.... Do you have any idea how this could be done?